# RDS instance advertised as having 8GB memory. Only showing 1GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm running a db.m4.large RDS instance. It is advertised everywhere as having 8GB of memory. Though on the monitoring screen it only shows ~1.2GB.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

[image: Screenshot showing 8GB]

[image: Only has 1GB]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/hosting tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS RDS scales that memory bar not by the total memory capacity but by the percentage of the threshold it is taking up. This would mean that somewhere in your AWS Console a auto-scaling or auto-alert threshold on RDS memory has been set at ~1.25 GiB.

I know this because, for example, I have an RDS instance with 2GiB memory but the memory bar shows what appears to be ~4GiB because that is the default threshold in my auto-scaling groups.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have a default threshold set, but I tried creating a new parameter group rather than using the default. After a reboot, it shows correctly now.

Comment: @beansontoast did you change any specific settings in the custom parameter group? I wonder if the change has anything to do with the parameter group, or if it was just the reboot that fixed it.

Comment: @Mark B No I don't think so. I just created a new parameter group without touching the settings, assigned it, rebooted and it corrected itself.

Comment: That parameter group would be identical to the default then.

Comment: My problem seems to have come back after another reboot. @Chris do you know where the auto threshold on RDS memory is found in the AWS interface?